# reactjs How to autoFocus specific input field when duplicated inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'd like to use the autoFocus attribute both inputs but when loaded the page, the first input field's focus on. I need to focus on modal input field instead on page. :D

```
//page
<Input
   placeholder="a"
   title="aa"
   autoFocus
/>    
//modal
<Input
   placeholder="a"
   title="aa"
   autoFocus
/>
```